# How can I add external class in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a class in `app/Libraries/TestClass.php` with following content:

```
class TestClass {
      public function getInfo() {
           return 'test';
      }
}
```

Now, I would like to call `getInfo()` method from this external class in my Controller.

How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First you should make sure that this class is in the right namespace. The correct namespace here would be:

```
namespace App\Libraries;

class TestClass {
```

Then you can just use it like any other class:

```
$test = new TestClass();
echo $test->getInfo();
```

Don't forget the import at the top of the class you want to use it in:

```
use App\Libraries\TestClass;
```

---

In case you don't have control over the namespace or don't want to change it, add an entry to `classmap` in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/Libraries"
    ]
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`. After that you'll be able to use it the same way as above except with a different (or no) namespace.